# How can I efficiently approximate the value of $\ln(x+1) - \ln(x)$?

Tags: logarithms, taylor-expansion, approximation

Additional: $x = 20$ and accuracy = $0.001$. I think that this function can be approximate using Maclaurin or Taylor series but I would like more opinions.

Comment: The issue is that when $x$ is large, the two will be close leading to spurious zeroes. I think simply doing $\ln(\frac{x + 1}{x}) = \ln(1 + \frac1x)$ should do fine.

Comment: If your software environment provides a function `log1p` (most do), use `log1p(1.0/x)`.